# Take all words with replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this code:

```
$(this).text().replace(/write\s(\w+);/g, "$1");
```

and this text:

```
write testing code;
```

but show only "testing"!
How to take all words and show "testing code"?

thx

Comment: why don't you just add the text you want to the `text.()` like this `$(this).text('testing code');`

Comment: \w does not match whitespace you need to rethink you regular expression

Comment: No need for a regex here.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log($("#my_element").text().replace("write",""));
```

You don't need a regex if replacing the string "write" is all you want to do.

To change the element's inner html:

```
 $("#my_element").html(($("#my_element").text().replace("write",""));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you want to strip out the word `write` from the string and keeping the other words? If this is the case, you can do it like this:

```
$(this).text().replace(/(\s?)write(\s?)/g, '');
```